# ds4drv not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth, gamepad

I am trying to get my dualshock 4 controller up and running on my Ubuntu 15.04 Laptop. 
I have previously (About a year and a half ago) used ds4drv without problems on the very same computer (It' s been reinstalled a few times since then).

Now nothing works with it, neither Bluetooth connection nor wired, so I am stuck with playing the games that have native Dualshock 4 support. 
When I run the ds4drv command I get 5 different errors from 2 files. I don' t know how to resolve these errors though. (See the picture).
[image: The error messages I am getting when launching ds4drv from a standard terminal]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
apt-get install python-evdev python3-evdev
```

The error message just indicates a missing Python package (`evdev>=0.3.0` not found).

Comment: It seemed to work, but the controller dosen' t respond very well. When I play games it switches around the X and Square button.